# Iterative merge with tables for values – conditioned on values between an interval (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I’m trying to merge two tables, where the rows of the left side stay unchanged and a column gets updated based on the right side. Thereby, the column of the left table is taking the value of the right side, if it is the highest value (i.e., higher then the current one on the left side) but below an individually set threshold.

The threshold is set by the column “Snapshop”; the column “Latest value found” indicates the highest so far observed value (within the threshold).

In order to be memory efficient, the process will work over many small chunks of data and needs to be able to iterate over a list of dataframes. In each dataframe the origin is recorded in column “Table ID”. If the main-dataframe finds a value it stores the origin in its column “Found in”.

### Example

#### Main table (left side)

```
+----+-------------------------------------------+--------------------+----------+
| ID | Snapshot timestamp (Maximum search value) | Latest value found | Found in |
+----+-------------------------------------------+--------------------+----------+
|  1 | Aug-18                                    | NULL               | NULL     |
|  2 | Aug-18                                    | NULL               | NULL     |
|  3 | May-18                                    | NULL               | NULL     |
|  4 | May-18                                    | NULL               | NULL     |
|  5 | May-18                                    | NULL               | NULL     |
+----+-------------------------------------------+--------------------+----------+
```

#### First data chunk

```
+-----+----------+-------------+--------------------+
| Idx | Table ID | Customer ID | Snapshot timestamp |
+-----+----------+-------------+--------------------+
|   1 | Table1   |           1 | Jan-14             |
|   2 | Table1   |           1 | Feb-14             |
|   3 | Table1   |           2 | Jan-14             |
|   4 | Table1   |           2 | Feb-14             |
|   5 | Table1   |           3 | Mar-14             |
+-----+----------+-------------+--------------------+
```

#### Result: Left-side after first merge

```
+----+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
| ID | Snapshot timestamp | Latest value found | Found in |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|  1 | Aug-18             | Feb-14             | Table1   |
|  2 | Aug-18             | Feb-14             | Table1   |
|  3 | May-18             | Mar-14             | Table1   |
|  4 | May-18             | NULL               | NULL     |
|  5 | May-18             | NULL               | NULL     |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
```

#### Second data chunk

```
+-----+----------+-------------+--------------------+
| Idx | Table ID | Customer ID | Snapshot timestamp |
+-----+----------+-------------+--------------------+
|   1 | Table2   |           1 | Mar-15             |
|   2 | Table2   |           1 | Apr-15             |
|   3 | Table2   |           2 | Feb-14             |
|   4 | Table2   |           3 | Feb-14             |
|   5 | Table2   |           4 | Aug-19             |
+-----+----------+-------------+--------------------+
```

#### Result: Left-side after second merge

```
+----+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
| ID | Snapshot timestamp | Latest value found | Found in |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|  1 | Aug-18             | Apr-15             | Table2   |
|  2 | Aug-18             | Feb-14             | Table1   |
|  3 | May-18             | Mar-14             | Table1   |
|  4 | May-18             | NULL               | NULL     |
|  5 | May-18             | NULL               | NULL     |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
```

### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Main dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1,2,3,4,5],
                  "Snapshot": ["2019-08-31", "2019-08-31","2019-05-31","2019-05-31","2019-05-31"],  # the maximum interval than can be used
                   "Latest_value_found": [None,None,None,None,None],
                   "Found_in": [None,None,None,None,None]}
)

# Data chunks used for updates
Table1 = pd.DataFrame({"Idx": [1,2,3,4,5],
                  "Table_ID": ["Table1", "Table1", "Table1", "Table1", "Table1"],
                   "Customer_ID": [1,1,2,2,3],
                   "Snapshot_timestamp": ["2019-01-31","2019-02-28","2019-01-31","2019-02-28","2019-03-30"]}
)
Table2 = pd.DataFrame({"Idx": [1,2,3,4,5],
                  "Table_ID": ["Table2", "Table2", "Table2", "Table2", "Table2"],
                   "Customer_ID": [1,1,2,3,4],
                   "Snapshot_timestamp": ["2019-03-31","2019-04-30","2019-02-28","2019-02-28","2019-08-31"]}
)

list_of_data_chunks = [Table1, Table2]

# work: iteration
for data_chunk in list_of_data_chunks:
    pass
    # here the merging is performed iteratively
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my workaround, although I would try not to do this in a loop if it's just two tables.  I removed your "idx" column from the joining tables.

```
df_list = [df,Table1,Table2]
main_df = df_list[0]

count_ = 0
for i in df_list[1:]:
    main_df = main_df.merge(i, how = 'left', on = 'ID').sort_values(by = ['ID','Snapshot_timestamp'], ascending = [True,False])
    main_df['rownum'] = main_df.groupby(['ID']).cumcount()+1
    if count_ < 1:
        main_df = main_df[main_df['rownum'] == 1].drop(columns = ['rownum','Latest_value_found','Found_in'])
        main_df['Latest_value_found'] = np.where(main_df['Snapshot'] > main_df['Snapshot_timestamp'], main_df['Snapshot_timestamp'], pd.NaT)
        main_df['Found_in'] = np.where(main_df['Snapshot'] > main_df['Snapshot_timestamp'], main_df['Table_ID'], np.NaN)
        main_df = main_df.drop(columns = ['Snapshot_timestamp','Table_ID']).reset_index(drop = True)
        count_ += 1
    else:
        main_df = main_df[main_df['rownum']==1].drop(columns = 'rownum').reset_index(drop = True)
        this_table = []
        this_date = []
        for i in main_df.index:
            curr_snapshot = pd.to_datetime(main_df.loc[i,'Snapshot'])
            curr_latest_val = pd.to_datetime(main_df.loc[i,'Latest_value_found'])
            curr_foundin = main_df.loc[i,'Found_in']
            next_foundin = main_df.loc[i,'Table_ID']
            next_snapshot = pd.to_datetime(main_df.loc[i,'Snapshot_timestamp'])
            if curr_snapshot > curr_latest_val and curr_snapshot > next_snapshot and curr_latest_val == next_snapshot:
                this_date.append(curr_latest_val)
                this_table.append(curr_foundin)
            elif curr_snapshot > curr_latest_val and curr_snapshot > next_snapshot and curr_latest_val > next_snapshot:
                this_date.append(curr_latest_val)
                this_table.append(curr_foundin)
            elif curr_snapshot > curr_latest_val and curr_snapshot > next_snapshot and curr_latest_val < next_snapshot:
                this_date.append(next_snapshot)
                this_table.append(next_foundin)
            elif pd.isnull(curr_latest_val) and next_snapshot < curr_snapshot:
                this_date.append(next_snapshot)
                this_table.append(next_foundin)
            else:
                this_date.append(curr_latest_val)
                this_table.append(curr_foundin)

        main_df = main_df.drop(columns = ['Latest_value_found','Found_in','Table_ID','Snapshot_timestamp'])
        main_df = pd.concat([main_df,pd.Series(this_date),pd.Series(this_table)], axis = 1).rename(columns = {0:'Latest_value_found',1:'Found_in'})
        count_ += 1
```

Comment: Thank you. You're answer helps but it seems to be "to iterative". Maybe I have a wrong mindset coming from SQL but I think this would be to inefficient.
I took two tables as an (plural) example. In my case its many hundreds.

Comment: Yes, you're right, if you need to merge hundreds of tables, you would probably need to pass some type of function, preferably not using loops where applicable.

Comment: Can you show how this works, please? I'm quite novel to Pandas and can't use SQL currently.